# Convert matlab statement to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I should convert the following matlab statement in python:

```
lam = find(abs(b)>tol,1,'first')-1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be useful if you provide some 'actual' b, tol and show what Matlab does

Answer (score 1):

NumPy doesn't have the capability to get the first matching one, [`not yet anyway`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2269).

So, we need to get all matching ones with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace `find` and `numpy.abs` would be the replacement for `abs`. Thus, it would be -

```
import numpy as np

lam = np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0][0]-1
```

Thus, we are getting all matching indices with `np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0]`, then getting the first index by indexing into its first element with `np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0][0]` and finally subtracting `1` from it, just like we did on MATLAB.

Sample run -

On MATLAB :

```
>> b = [-4,6,-7,-2,8];
>> tol = 6;
>> find(abs(b)>tol,1,'first')-1
ans =
     2
```

On NumPy :

```
In [23]: a = np.array([-4,6,-7,-2,8])

In [24]: tol = 6

In [25]: np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0][0]-1
Out[25]: 1 # 1 lesser than MATLAB vesion because of 0-based indexing
```

For performance, I would suggest using [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to give us the index of the first matching one, rather than computing all matching indices with `np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0]`, like so -

```
In [40]: np.argmax(np.abs(a)>tol)-1
Out[40]: 1
```

Comment: `argmax` fails if there is no first element

Comment: Anf if I want the "last" instead of  the "first" ?

Comment: @Linux `np.where(np.abs(a)>tol)[0][-1]`.

Comment: Ah ok . Thank you very much for your kind support.